# apache nutch 2.3 2.x solr 4.8 hbase

Tags: apache, solr, hbase, nutch

I installed apache nutch 2.3,solr 4.8 and hbase 0.9 and crawled website and got content. I want to index crawled content based on HEADER Data, HTML Tag,Tag class name or Tag id Or Crawled such way that easily fetch content HEADER Data, HTML Tag,Tag class name or Tag id .I Googed got some idea also most of them for nutch 1.x. 
Please Help me.